# To skip country code or to make non-editable country code in Jquery Intel-Telephone plugin

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, focus

I have Phone number field to enter Number with Country Code and Flag. My problem is when i am moving from `Title` field to `Phone No` the focus is on `+1` 
[image: How it looks like]and when user start typing the number `+1` field is gonna overwritten. Is there any way to skip the focus on country code and start typing from Highlighted field [image: I want like this] or can we make country code non-editable. Remember Country-code can be maximum of 4 excluding `+`.

Comment: Instead of having it as text input, make it span

Comment: Didn't get you?

Comment: something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ucf0jym1/)

Comment: That is good..but believe me can't do any changes now related to UI :(

Comment: Can you share a sample markup code or make a fiddle?

Comment: i am using Jquery Telephone plugin itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124498/discussion-between-rajesh-and-steve).

Comment: What options have you used to configure the telephone plugin? Can you update [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9wp3stx/2/) to semo your issue?

Comment: @Dhananjay i was using 0.9.2 rather than 9.0.14 version of Jquery...but whatever you provided...it is good and working for me but only in Add page..means if i want to edit user..flag will not appear corresponding to the Phone number entered in Add..How to manage phone number with same flag in Edit